# How to add Java network server into OSGI bundle

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, osgi

I created this Java network server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EchoServer
{        
    ServerSocket m_ServerSocket;


    public EchoServer() 
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the server socket.
            m_ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(12111);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not create server socket at 12111. Quitting.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("Listening for clients on 12111...");

        // Successfully created Server Socket. Now wait for connections.
        int id = 0;
        while(true)
        {                        
            try
            {
                // Accept incoming connections.
                Socket clientSocket = m_ServerSocket.accept();

                // accept() will block until a client connects to the server.
                // If execution reaches this point, then it means that a client
                // socket has been accepted.

                // For each client, we will start a service thread to
                // service the client requests. This is to demonstrate a
                // multithreaded server, although not required for such a
                // trivial application. Starting a thread also lets our
                // EchoServer accept multiple connections simultaneously.

                // Start a service thread

                ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(clientSocket, id++);
                cliThread.start();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception encountered on accept. Ignoring. Stack Trace :");
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new EchoServer();    
    }


    class ClientServiceThread extends Thread
    {
        Socket m_clientSocket;        
        int m_clientID = -1;
        boolean m_bRunThread = true;

        ClientServiceThread(Socket s, int clientID)
        {
            m_clientSocket = s;
            m_clientID = clientID;
        }

        public void run()
        {            
            // Obtain the input stream and the output stream for the socket
            // A good practice is to encapsulate them with a BufferedReader
            // and a PrintWriter as shown below.
            BufferedReader in = null; 
            PrintWriter out = null;

            // Print out details of this connection
            System.out.println("Accepted Client : ID - " + m_clientID + " : Address - " + 
                             m_clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());

            try
            {                                
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(m_clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

                // At this point, we can read for input and reply with appropriate output.

                // Run in a loop until m_bRunThread is set to false
                while(m_bRunThread)
                {                    
                    // read incoming stream
                    String clientCommand = in.readLine();

                    System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);


                    if(clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
                    {
                        // Special command. Quit this thread
                        m_bRunThread = false;   
                        System.out.print("Stopping client thread for client : " + m_clientID);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Echo it back to the client.
                        out.println(clientCommand);
                        out.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean up
                try
                {                    
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    m_clientSocket.close();
                    System.out.println("...Stopped");
                }
                catch(IOException ioe)
                {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to insert this code into OSGI bundle. At the moment I don't have configured Glassfish with datasource to test the bundle. What I have to do in order to configure the Java server to listen for incomming connections when I deploy it on Glassfish server?

Do I need to add somenthing into the OSGI bundle activator to make the Java server listen for incoming network connections?

Best Wishes

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to just create your EchoServer object in the start() method and as far as I see it will start working. You could think about running it in a separate thread in order not to block your bundle's activity.

Comment: You *should* run the server in a separate thread, as the OSGi specification mandates that the start() (and stop()) method of a bundle activator should return as quickly as possible.